# How to handle junk character(such as a rectangle box contains 0,0,1,B) in java?

Tags: java

I am reading logs from the remote server while reading it, in output, it shows some garbage character(a rectangle box contains 0,0,1,B) while in logs it shows the actual value only

Please check attached screenshot([image]) for the same.

I am not sure how to handle this and print the exact value instead of garbage string.

Below is the code which I am using to read the data from remote server

```
    JSch jsch = new JSch();
    String privateKeyPath = "/home/abc/.ssh/id_rsa";
    jsch.addIdentity(privateKeyPath);
    Properties config = new Properties();
    config.put("StrictHostKeyChecking", "no");

    Session session = jsch.getSession("user",0.0.0.0 22);
    session.setConfig(config);
    session.connect();
    Channel channel = session.openChannel("shell");
    OutputStream ops = channel.getOutputStream();
    PrintStream ps = new PrintStream(ops, true);
    channel.connect();
    ps.println("cdbb" + "&&" +"tail -f ../logs/bbmq.log | grep -i 
    'saurabh'");
    InputStream in=channel.getInputStream();
    byte[] tmp=new byte[1024];
    while(true){
        int i=in.read(tmp, 0, 1024);
        if(i<0)
            break;
        System.out.print(new String(tmp, 0, i));
    }
```

Comment: can be useful https://misc.flogisoft.com/bash/tip_colors_and_formatting

Comment: Whatever is producing those messages thinks it's writing to a terminal that accepts color/formatting escape sequences.  It's probably old legacy code intended originally to be run from the command line.  You'll have to remove the escape sequences in your Java code.

Answer (score 0):

After looking at your image, I can assume that your log contains ANSI terminal escape sequences (compatible with the old VT100-VT220 series terminals) introduced with <kbd>Esc</kbd> [

As per displaying the exact value, the *garbage* **is** what the file contains, so it is the actual value. Your log seems to contain only the Esc [ ... m and Esc [ K escape sequences, so you could try to filter them out.